# MySQL join two Tables to n:m Relation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables (Table 1 and Table 2) and I want to create a table (Table 3) with the ID's. So to speak a n to m relationship table.

```
Table 1
1 Mark
2 George
3 David

Table 2
5 Bank
6 Construction
7 Carfactory

Table 3
1 5
1 6
1 7
2 5
2 6
2 7
3 5
3 6
3 7
```

I can make it so that the rows from table 1 are taken from 1 to 3 but not as to the row 1 all rows are taken from the table 2. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Looks like a cross join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your expected output using [CROSS JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

```
SELECT table1.id,table2.id FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it what i need.